# How to split a string into two parts

Tags: delphi

I have a string I type in such as `{ !move simon General Chat }`.
I want to strip the first and the full 2nd phrase from string no matter the size. The code below works perfectly just for `General Chat`, but if I change this 'area id' to say `Romance` or `spacegames` it does not work.

What should I change to the code?

```
if UpperCase(Mid(source,1,5)) = UpperCase('!move') then
begin
  User := Mid(source, 6, length(source)); // remove !move from username
  RoomID := Mid(source, length(User)-6, length(source)); // remove !move and username
  SendMemo.Clear;
  MoveUserTo(IMData.m_UserID, GetFirstNWrods(User, ' ', 1), GetFirstNWrods(RoomID, ' ', 3));
end;

function GetFirstNWrods(const str: string; const delim: string; Numwords: Integer): string;
var
  Tokenizer: IStringTokenizer;
begin
  Result := '';
  Tokenizer := StringTokenizer(str, delim);
  while (Tokenizer.hasMoreTokens) and (Numwords > 0) do
  begin
    Result := Result + Tokenizer.nextToken + delim;
    Dec(Numwords)
  end;
  System.Delete(Result, Length(Result) - Length(delim) + 1, Length(delim));
end;
```

Comment: Why not user the tokenizer to pull off the command. Your code will treat `!movex` as if it were `!move` and that's not what you want. We don't have all of your code. We don't know what your rules on delimiters are. Wrod should be Word.

Comment: Please give more examples of your input and required output *and tell how many many words are in your 'part 1' and 'part 2'*. Put all strings in between `backticks` (backquotes) to prevent us having to ask: *Are those { } part of your string*?

Comment: in chat area I would type     !move Simon General Chat, then code would get Simon as first part then General Chat as 2nd part

Comment: You have not addressed any of the points made above

Comment: words would be any number basicly it be down to the size of the persons name and the size of the location name so can be anything from 3 to 35

source holds the string sent from memo which is just {!move Simon General Chat}

code would then split needed information to display other then that I really dont understand what your asking sorry

Comment: If the number of words in the persons name varies *and* the number of words in the room name varies, this cannot be solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a coincidence that your solution works for General Chat. 
In third line of your code:

```
User := Mid(source, 6, length(source)); // remove !move from username
```

you actually copy to `User` all the remaining string, which is  `simon General Chat`. In your next line:

```
RoomID := Mid(source, length(User)-6, length(source)); // remove !move and username
```

something strange is happening. Length of User is less by 6 than length of source, and now you take your RoomID to be exactly 12 right positions, and that doesn't depend on actual contents of your string.

So, your code works normally if RoomID is 11 or 12 symbols long (leading space will be removed later if there is any). What a surprise: `General chat` has length 12, so it works.

What you actually need to do is to read word after word to `User` variable and check at each step, if there is user with such name. To work unambiguously, you should NEVER have user whose name contains name of another user at the beginning (that's what Jan Doggen was telling you). For example, if you have user `simon`, you should not allow anybody else to have username `simon paul`, otherwise it's much more difficult to parse your command.

So, you read word after word until it yields existing user name. Now all that remains is your RoomID.

Comment: names are protected and only that person can use it so thats no issue problem is the length trying to get the correct length of lobby name always I do pick the tasks lol and sorry for being slow my reading is not so good so takes me a little while to understand things I dont mean to be a pain